# if $M \otimes_A (A_m/mA_m)=0$ for every maximal ideal $m \subset A$, then $M=0$, $M$ finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, localization, finitely-generated

> Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module. Prove that if $M \otimes_A (A_m/mA_m)=0$ for every maximal ideal $m \subset A$, then $M=0$. Subscrpit $_m$ means localization at $m$.

First consider the exact sequence
$$m \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/m \rightarrow 0.$$
Since localization of modules is an exact functor, we have
$$mA_m \rightarrow A_m \rightarrow A_m/mA_m \rightarrow 0$$
is exact. Taking tensor product gives us
$$M \underset{A}{\otimes}mA_m \rightarrow M \underset{A}{\otimes}A_m \rightarrow M \underset{A}{\otimes}A_m/mA_m \rightarrow0$$
which is exact. Note that $M \underset{A}{\otimes}A_m \simeq M_m$ and by assumption $M \underset{A}{\otimes}A_m/mA_m=0$.

Now using $M$ is finitely generated, how can I show that $M_m=0$?

If I can show this then since $M=0 \Leftrightarrow (M_m=0$ for all maximal ideals $m$ of $A$), I can complete the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$M \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak m}/\mathfrak mA_{\mathfrak m}\simeq M_{\mathfrak m}/\mathfrak mM_{\mathfrak m}.$$
Then use *Nakayama's lemma*.

Answer (score 2):

The last exact sequence with the appropriate identifications becomes $mM_m\rightarrow M_m\rightarrow0$ and so $M_m=mM_m$. Now apply Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: Thanks both of you and Nakayama!

Comment: Btw doesn't Nakayama's lemma only work for $M=IM$ where $I$ is contained in every maximal ideal (i.e intersection of every maximal ideal)? $m$ is just a random maximal ideal and is not necessarily contained every maximal ideal.

Comment: @Andrew $A_m$ is a local ring.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.